# How can I make Conditional Formatting work for my Cognos Report

Tags: reporting, cognos

I have a simple list report in Cognos 8.3.  I have a field with things like this:

```
ETLJobX Completed - SUCCESS
ETLJobY Completed - FAIL
ETLJobZ Completed - SUCCESS
ETLJobA Completed - SUCCESS
ETLJobB Completed - FAIL
```

I have a conditional formatter set to color the successes in green and failures in red.  Works perfectly.  Using the conditions "Contains" SUCCESS or FAIL in the string.

If I change the data so that a row looks like this:

```
ETLJobX Completed - SUCCESS
Job used in Report X

ETLJobY Completed - FAIL
Job used in Report Y
```

it no longer colors that row.  The carriage return seems to break things.  If I type the same data as :

```
ETLJobX Completed - SUCCESS Job used in Report X
```

So that it is on one line, the conditional format works fine.

Is there any way to make this work on lines with a carriage return in them?

Comment: Very strange... I was able to duplicate the behavior in 8.4 as well.  I tried several approaches, including creating a conditional variable to use as a style variable using 'LIKE %SUCCESS%' instead of using 'CONTAINS' and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that worked for me (on version 8.4) is to create a conditional variable like this: `position ('SUCCESS', [Query1].[test]) > -1`.  Assign the new condition as the style variable for the column you want to apply the conditional formatting to.  Using the `LIKE` or `CONTAINS` operators in the same manner does not seem to work if the expression contains the carriage return.